# What is left on the hard drive

Tags: anonymity

If nothing is downloaded, is there anything left behind on the hard drive. Say viewing a video
or reading an article.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html)? Ideally nothing.

New bugs are unfortunately found from time to time and then fixed. One current example is the [clipboard “cache”](https://bugs.torproject.org/9701).

If disk leaks are a problem in your threat model, use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). It gives you the guarantee that nothing will be written on disks, unless explicitly done as a user action.